# TypeError: makeUser is not a function discord js V12

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

`(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: makeUser is not a function`
Hello I tried to make a command for when the person does the command automatically adds 1 line in a cfg called users.json but this gives me this error.
Again, as I was updating my bot to discord.js V12 I got an error:
`TypeError: makeUser is not a function`
Here is a part the code:

````js
if (!config.servers.servidores.includes(args[4])) {
console.log(yellow + "[" + moment.tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format('HH:mm A') + "] " + red + `[DB]` + reset + ` ${msg.author.username} ` + l7yellow + `->` +  lightred + ` Configuração Errada` + reset + ` Status: ` + red + `Servidor` + reset)
const metodoembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor("#ff0000")
  .setTitle("Database Editor -> Atom")
  .setDescription("An `error` was identified when\nmodifying the database.")
  .addField('**Type:**', '```http\n' + 'Server' + '```', true)
  .addField('Solution:', 'Check the available\nservers in the database', true)
  .setThumbnail(`${msg.author.displayAvatarURL}`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter(`${msg.author.username}`, `${msg.author.displayAvatarURL}`);
return msg.channel.send(metodoembed); }
//
function updategive(file, json) {
  fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(json, null, 2), "utf8", function(err) {
    console.log(purple + "[" + reset + moment.tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format('HH:mm A') + purple + "] " + `[] Banco de Dados atualizado.`);
  });
}
if (!users[person]) {
  makeUser(person);
}
users[person].attackTime = time;
users[person].concurrents = conc;
users[person].servers = servers;
users[person].expire = moment(expire).unix();
updategive("users.json", users);
return msg.channel.send(responsegive);

}
````

The error is occuring in this line:

```js
if (!users[person]) {
  makeUser(person);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what `makeUser` is?

Answer (score 0):

Hello seems like you are using a function that is not existing. Create a function with the name `makeUser` and the parameter `user`. So it should look like this `function makeUser(user) {...}`.

Also if you are using discord.js v12, make sure you replace `RichEmbed` with `MessageEmbed`.

Comment: Like this? `function makeUser(user) {person}
if (!users[person]) {
  makeUser(person);
}`

Comment: No this is not possible because inside your `makeUser` function you are using `person` (without any sense btw) although you have to provide `user` (so you have to work with `user` inside your `makeUser` function.